# rspec remote webhook without stubbing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a Rails app that receives a simple POST webhook from a remote system. I'm trying to create a rspec where I trigger the remote system to send a webhook and process it in my app. I can confirm that the webhook is generated by the remote system when triggered, how do I listen to it in rspec?

I can't use something like `requestbin` or `VCR` since the webhook body is different for each call.

I search all over the web & SO for a solution, but I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To test how your application responds to incoming requests just create a [request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec) that sends a post request to your application:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Webhooks", type: :request do
  it "handles the response" do
    post '/path/to/your/webhook', 
       params: { foo: 'bar' }, 
       headers: { 'x-foo' => 'bar' }
    expect(something).to happen
  end
end
```

Here you would send a typical webhook payload as specified by documentation of the service and write examples based on which behavior it triggers in your application. While the might not have the accuity of actually triggering the webhook its a lot faster, simpler and idempotent as you know that the test won't trigger any unwanted side effects on the external service.

Triggering an actual webhook and waiting for it to send a response is a bit more problematic as its asyncronous in nature. RSpec does not have built in support for async tests but it can at least in theory be done with the [async gem](https://github.com/socketry/async-rspec). You also have to ensure that the service has a testing mode to give some degree of idempotency.